# Enviar respuesta de usuario de un alert js a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

necesito crear la funcionalidad que cuando el usuario intente salir del navegador o hacer click en otro botón del menú, le muestre el alert que se perderá la información si sale del proceso , y si el usuario clickea en aceptar se envié esta variable true o false   para usarla y crear la funcionalidad  con php,  necesariamente con php  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para manejar la salida del usuario de la página actual y enviar la respuesta del usuario a un script de php sería de la siguiente manera, con javascript y jQuery para poder hacer la petición `ajax`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    var result = confirm("¿Estás seguro de querer salir?, se perderá la información");

    ajaxSalida(result);

    return result;
  }


  function ajaxSalida(result){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {result: result}
    }).done(function(response) {

    }).fail(function(data) {

    });
  }
```

Las peticiones `ajax` una vez lanzadas, aunque el usuario decida salir, se completan.

Comment: Muchas gracias Aarón  , pero disculpa cómo hago para capturar el result con PHP ? Es que es la primera ves que uso Ajax y estado intentado con post  pero mejor te pregunto jeje .

Comment: @Mañany Pues al ajax le estás específicando una ruta de a donde mandará los datos, en este caso, yo te puse como ejemplo un archivo que se debería de encontrar en el mismo directorio que el archivo en donde se encuentra el ajax y se debe de llamar `script.php`, dentro de este archivo php, recibes el parámetro como: `$result = $_POST['result']`.

Comment: Ya lo hice, ahora algo pasa pero no se envía la variable al script.php, quizás me hace falta el uso de alguna librería pero ya estoy usando jQuery

Comment: @Mañany Haz un `echo` de lo que sea y checa en consola si siquiera está accediendo al archivo correctamente, recuerda que en `ajax` no se recarga la página.